# No line found error when reading from file to Array

Tags: java

Hello thanks for taking the time to answer this. I am working on an assignment where I have to read names and scores from a txt file into arrays using a scanner. I cannot use arrayList (oh how much easier this would be). Anyway I keep pulling line not found errors. What am I missing. 
The data being read in is formatted as such:

```
Puckett, Karen
10 10 9.5 10 10 8 9.5 10 10 10 9 10 10 10 0
4 3 5 3 5 2 3 2 1.5 1 5 3.5
17.5 24 22 23.5 22 23
90 91
96
```

code starts here

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Cade
*/
public class CS1180Project04McLarty {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int studentCount = 16;
        int LabCount = 16;
        int quizCount = 12;

        double [] projectGrades;
        double [] examGrades;
        double [] finalsGrade;
        double [] labGrades = new double[LabCount];
        double [] quizGrades = new double [quizCount];
        String [] names = new String[studentCount];

        File doc = new File("scores.txt");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(doc);

        names = fileReaderNames(studentCount ,doc, fin); 

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i]);
        }
    }


    /**
    * reads in names only
    * @param studentCount int count of students set to 16 in main
    * @param doc file being read 
    * @param fin scanner 
    * @return complete Array of the names
    */
    private static String[] fileReaderNames(int studentCount, File doc, Scanner fin ) {
        int count = 0;
        String [] names = new String[studentCount];
        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            names[count] = fin.nextLine();
            fin.nextLine();
            fin.nextLine();
            fin.nextLine();
            fin.nextLine();
            fin.nextLine();
            count++;
        }
        fin.close();
        return names;
    }
}
```

Comment: inside `while (fin.hasNext())` why do you use 5 `nextLine()` ?

Comment: Q edited to show format

Comment: You check if there is one more line to read : fin.hasNext() and then read 6 lines. But you always need to check before you read a line.

Comment: @CadeMcLarty Don't put that in a comment. It's unreadable. Edit the question.

Comment: Have you tried debugging what it is trying to read?  change `names[count] = fin.nextLine();` to `System.out.println("A: " + (names[count] = fin.nextLine()));` and `fin.nextLine();` to `System.out.println("B: " + fin.nextLine();` and so on A, B, C, D, E, F depending on which line you're reading

Comment: @phflack just did its reading all of the names in, it looks like the loop is continuing to run

Comment: What was the last thing to print? one of the `A: ...` lines or one of the `F: ...` lines?

Comment: @phflack missed data in the file when I copied it over so it was reading lines that do not exist

Comment: If the debugging output always had `A: (name)` and `B-F: (scores)` then there shouldn't be any issues, if you're missing one line mid-way through then it will be `F: (name)` and `A-E: (scores)` which is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code expects names followed by 5 lines (I guess some other data), but because of that you only test every 6th line exists. If any other line is missing (that means the total number of lines is not a multiple of 6 for any reason) it will fail.

Comment: Thanks i went back to look at the file and I had missed 1 piece of data making the list a non multiple of six replaced it and its running like it should.